# augmented reality in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, augmented-reality

Sample app which implements google maps for getting overlays at particular lat/lng.I would like to implement Augmented reality  feature to the current app.can you tell me how to achieve it? Is there any tutorial or video for the same ,I looked into Mixare and the link below    but the json response should follow the same provided on the website,I have custom response .Please can anyone guide me to achieve the above requirement .

I looked into the link  http://www.quora.com/Which-AR-Augmented-Reality-libraries-exist-on-Android-iPhone  but there is nothing in detailed format or step by step implementation of the same .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in the future mixare will allow to pass data through extras, instead of through an URL.

You can try the feature right now using the development branch. See [this g+ post](https://plus.google.com/b/112059518295078178208/112059518295078178208/posts/QzbA1Rv3JQG) for further info.

HTH,
Daniele

P.s. The same JSON format you already know is supported when using the Extras.

Comment: Hi Daniele thanks for the quick reply.I have a response in this format and on click I would like to show his name with android dialog box,let me know how to proceed .I have downloaded the source code and I get nearest location ,I would like to change it with my response as below:

Comment: {
 "JSArray": [{
  "JsLogin": {
   "email": "testing",
   "latitude": "36.931159,",
   "longitude": "-120.102539",
   "username": "testing",
   "distance": "0.00217541222604626"
  }
 },
 {
  "JsLogin": {
   "email": "testing2",
   "latitude": "36.951794",
   "longitude": "-120.165024",
   "username": "testng2",
   "distance": "3.17649190009442"
  }
 }]
}